# How to configure PhpStorm to read GoLang environment variable GOROOT from Vagrant VM

Tags: go, vagrant, phpstorm

How can one configure `GOROOT` setting in PhpStorm to read the value from a Vagrant VM?

My host is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm connect to the VM. Read this¹ text from a JetBrains conference and see if it helps.

[1] https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+Advanced+Vagrant+features+in+PhpStorm